# Is there a way to avoid to call dl.google.com and maven when build a flutter android project?

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using gradle 5.6.2. Actually, this is a flutter project and I build it using:

```
flutter build apk
```

My project has 2 build.gradle files:

```
  android/
  ---- build.gragle
  ---- app/
       ---- build.gradle
```

I deleted the `google()` and `jcenter()` reposistories from the parent build.gradle, and configured a nexus repository. My buiild.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        if (!hasProperty('NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR')) {
            ext.NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR = ''
        }
            
        if (!hasProperty('NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW')) {
            ext.NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW = ''
        }    
        maven {
            credentials  {
                username = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
                password = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
            }
            url "https://somenexusrepo.com/repository/maven-google-android"
        }
        maven {
            credentials  {
                username = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
                password = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
            }
            url "https://somenexusrepo.com/repository/maven-public"
        }
        maven {
            credentials  {
                username = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
                password = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
            }
            url "https://somenexusrepo.com/repository/maven-snapshots"
        }
        maven {
            credentials  {
                username = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
                password = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
            }
            url "https://somenexusrepo.com/repository/maven-group"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        if (!hasProperty('NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR')) {
            ext.NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR = ''
        }
            
        if (!hasProperty('NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW')) {
            ext.NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW = ''
        }    
        maven {
            credentials  {
                username = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
                password = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
            }
            url "https://somenexusrepo.com/repository/maven-google-android"
        }
        maven {
            credentials  {
                username = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
                password = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
            }
            url "https://somenexusrepo.com/repository/maven-public"
        }
        maven {
            credentials  {
                username = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
                password = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
            }
            url "https://somenexusrepo.com/repository/maven-snapshots"
        }
        maven {
            credentials  {
                username = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR}"
                password = "${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW}"
            }
            url "https://somenexusrepo.com/repository/maven-group"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"

    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

But when I try to build the project, it still tries to get some dependencies from other repositories. I'm trying to build it from a private network and I can not access either dl.google.com or repo.maven.apache.org repositories, that's why I am getting this error:

```
 A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
[        ] > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration 'classpath'.
[        ]    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
[        ]      Required by:
[        ]          unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
[        ]       > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
[        ]          > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
[        ]             > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
[        ]                > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com, dl.google.com] failed: No route to host (connect failed)
[        ]       > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0.
[        ]          > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
[        ]             > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.pom'.
[        ]                > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org, repo.maven.apache.org] failed: connect timed out
```

Even if I try to execute `gradle build` command, I get the same error.

Is there a way to avoid using these repositories?

Comment: Try ```flutter build clean``` then ```flutter build apk```